# Polling implementation using setInterval in knockout application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am trying to implement simple polling mechanism using setInterval. I have a Viewmodel as follows:

```
define([ 'knockout', 'jquery',
    ], function ( ko, $) {
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        //setInterval( function() {
        $.ajax({url: "", async: false,timeout: 3000, success: function (data) {
           // some operation

            }, dataType: "json"});
      //}, 3000);

    }
    return ViewModel;


 });
```

Upto this it works fine ajax call return data and does operation.How do I use setInterval so that ajax call returns data after certain interval so that ViewModel is updated and data get refreshed in UI? If I uncomment the setInterval block then ViewModel is not getting returned to the DOM.I think setInterval is asynchronous. Any solutions is appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example on jsfiddle? They have an [AJAX echo service](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) you can use to have AJAX in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, using `setInterval` with async code is not the best way to go. It's better to use `setTimeout` to schedule a new request once the previous one has finished.

If you make sure there can't be two pending requests at once, you can access your `ViewModel` instance through `self` in your success handler and you won't have to worry of older/other requests undoing your change.

Here's an example:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  var INTERVAL = 5000;
  var timeout = null;
  var currentReq = null;
  
  this.observableProp = ko.observable("empty");

  var fetchNewData = function() {
    currentReq = $.ajax( /* options */);
    
    currentReq
      .done(processNewData)
      .always(scheduleNewDataFetch);
  };

  var processNewData = function(data) {
    // self refers to your current ViewModel instance
    // set observable properties using self.prop(data)
    self.observableProp("data");
  };
  
  var scheduleNewDataFetch = function() {
    if (currentReq) {
      currentReq.abort();  
    }
    
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);  
    }
    
    currentReq = null;
    timeout = setTimeout(fetchNewData, INTERVAL);
    
  };

  fetchNewData(); // Starts the update loop
}
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty good  but even  define([ 'knockout', 'jquery',
    ], function ( ko, $) {
    function ViewModel() {
   //your implementation
    }
    return ViewModel;
 });  is returning  ViewModel as undifined .Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm afraid that's a different problem and doesn't really relate to _this_ question. Try googling for "amd define returns undefined" or ask a new question with the relevant tags and code. Might be a circular dependency, who knows...

Answer (score -1):

You could try simply doing:

```
define([ 'knockout', 'jquery',
    ], function ( ko, $) {
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        var refreshInterval = /* your refresh interval in ms here*/;
        setInterval( function() {
            $.ajax({url: "", async: false, success: function (data) {
                // some operation

                timeout: refreshInterval
                }, dataType: "json"});
        }, refreshInterval);

    }
    return ViewModel;

 });
```

The ajax call is made every `refreshInterval` (in ms). The `timeout` property is a security to be sure the answer you get during one interval are the data of this interval, and not the data from a previously unanswered call that got late.

Comment: Doesnot work ViewModel does not get returned to the html.