# How to Reload Function after Interval Time

Tags: knockout.js

I recently creating SPA that can simply monitor ICMP of the hosts, then I found [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/) and thought this could get the job done. But, I need the app to ping every given interval time not once when *onload* event trigerred.

I already tried several changes like this, but still no luck:

```
var komodel = new PingModel([
    '192.168.9.49',
]);
window.setInterval(komodel,1000);
ko.applyBindings(komodel);
```

This is my first time deal with Knockout and I am really excited. Cheers.

Thank You.

Comment: Your question is a similar to this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582401/polling-implementation-using-setinterval-in-knockout-application.  You also have async calls with ` this.img.onload`.  In fact, you are not performing an ICMP call, but trying to load an image wich url is not an image, but this is another question, of course.  :-)

Comment: Indeed. It stated like this: _"maybe not 'ping exactly' but seems to work"_.